# Stream over continous Socket Android/Java

Tags: java, android, image, sockets, stream

I´m trying to send pictures from my phone to my PC, one at a time, but not opening a new Socket for every picture as I think this is not a very performant way. My problem is, that I only recieve the first picture and no more. But the first picture is also not "complete": it shows me the first 2 rows of pixel and the rest is just the same color as the last pixel from row 2.
I think the problem is on the Server side as I can display the images on my phone. I´m also very new to streams and thankful for every help I can get!

## Client

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream memoryStream = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmapToSend =
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapToSend, 900, 800, true);
            bitmapToSend.compress(
                 Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, memoryStream);
            byte[] byteArray = memoryStream.toByteArray();
            memoryStream = null;

            DataOutputStream outputStream = 
                      new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeInt(byteArray.length);
            outputStream.write(byteArray);
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Socket not created");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

## Server

```
public static void readImages(InputStream stream) throws IOException    {

DataInputStream imgInput = new DataInputStream(stream);
int index = 0;
int byteLength;

try {
    while ((byteLength = imgInput.readInt())>0) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[byteLength];
        imgInput.read(buffer);

        OutputStream imgOutput = new FileOutputStream("current" + (index++) + ".jpg");
        imgOutput.write(buffer);
        imgOutput.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        imgInput.close();
    } catch (IOException f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what does `imgInput.read(buffer)` return? something != `byteLength`?

Comment: yes it returns something significantly smaller than `byteLength`. That would explain the small part of pixels in the image. So how can you insure Java to read a specific amount of bytes?

Comment: loop your `read`s? or try `readFully`

Comment: `readFully()` it is! Thank you sir!

Comment: sure, your welcome